# Where is AccountKey for CosmosDB in Azure portal

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to migrate mongodb data to Cosmos db. The migration tool I am using, is asking for "AccountKey" required to connect the Cosmosdb.

I am not able to get the account key in azure portal.

https://portal.azure.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the **AccountKey** from **`Settings -> ConnectionString -> Primary Password`** when you click on your cosmosDB resource

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to upload json file to cosmos through migration, it is not creating any id field. So it is throwing error. Any idea which option need to choose in migration tool.

Comment: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5aa8bf0077bbfe296c1727de" }, "_t" : "DiscreteProperty", "Name" : "AHRI_bCertified"
}


I am using dt migration tool by micosoft. It uploads documents. But not viewing because of "_id" is not there in collection

Comment: @Manas Kumar any issue during migrate is another question, you should create another SO thread. Sajeetharan have answered the question where is Account Key in the Azure portal.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I recommened that OP to create another SO thread, if have another question. I updated the comment. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to `Settings -> Keys` to view Primary Key as well as Connection String for CosmosDB in Azure Portal

[image]

Comment: It's good to change management interface time to time to keep devs busy. This seems to be currently right way to find needed credentials to connect with cosmos db.