# Where is the Azure Cosmos DB Keys page located in the Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I tried to follow this article [Connect to Azure Cosmos DB from BI and Data Integration tools with the ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/odbc-driver) but I'm unable to locate the DB Keys page mentioned on step 3.

I found something similar to the image, but it is for the connection string.

[image: I found something similar to the image, but it is for the connection string.]

Here's the screenshot of the menu options, "Keys" is not on the list.

[image]

Comment: No, you're in the right place. You even highlighted the two things you need with URI and Primary Key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320441/where-is-accountkey-for-cosmosdb-in-azure-portal

Comment: If you do not see Keys in the navigation bar on the left it is quite likely you do not have rights to view them. Check with the subscription owner and ask if you are restricted. This is the action you need to access keys, "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/listKeys/action"

Answer (score 0):

**No-SQL Instance**

In the **CosmosDB** blade and then **Keys** ...

[image: Cosmos DB Keys]

**Mongo DB Instance**

You'll find the connection string in the **Quick Start** section of the blade.

[image: Mongo DB]

I'd normally just post a comment for a question like this but it's hard to show you without showing a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you Skin! I don't see "Keys", is it possible I don't have access to it?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screenshot of what you can see?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question to include the menu options.

Comment: Ok, you have a mongo DB instance, is that expected?

Comment: Yes, this is expected. Does this function not available to the Cosmo mongo DB instance?

Comment: No, there are on keys for the Mongo instance.  Sorry, only just got back to this.  The link you shared doesn't really talk about Mongo DB so I suspect it's pointing more towards the no-SQL instance.  I've updated my answer.